# HighlightImage does not work consistently with Line

Tags: graphics, bugs, image

**Bug introduced in 10.2, fixed in 11**

---

[`HighlightImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightImage.html) is supposed to work with graphics-primitives like `Line` and `Circle` too. Very simple examples show, that this does not work consistently.

The documentation clearly indicates, that it should be possible to call (omitting the `Graphics`!)

```
HighlightImage[img, Rectangle[{132.5, 88.5}, {220.5, 176.5}], ...]
```

but if you try it, surprising results are thrown at you. Please look at the differences:

```
img = Image[Table[i, {i, 0, 255}, {256}], "Byte"];
lines = Table[Line[{{i, 1}, {i, 256}}], {i, 1, 256, 8}];
HighlightImage[img, lines]
HighlightImage[img, Graphics[lines]]
```

(this seems to work in version 10.3)

[image: Mathematica graphics] [image: Mathematica graphics]

One is missing lines and the other one is blurry (although we have perfect pixel positions). A even more amusing one is this

```
HighlightImage[img, lines, "HighlightColor" -> Blue, Method -> {"Boundary", 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 10.3, this call returns an error

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Additionally, there seems to be issues regarding the rasterization-quality

```
circles = Table[Circle[{128, 128}, r], {r, 1, 128, 10}];
HighlightImage[img, circles]
HighlightImage[img, Graphics@circles]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics] [image: Mathematica graphics]

This looks like it was not well tested before thrown at users. I needed the highlighting with lines and ended up writing the 10 lines of code myself, after fiddling around with `HighlightImage` for half an hour.

Comment: To meet the requirements for the bugs tag, let's state for the record that I encountered this bug under v10.2 Win7-64 as well, though my first picture [looks slightly different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q8cxC.png).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm very generous with the bug-tag when I'm sure it is not intended behavior and the margin for it being a feature is impossibly small :-) Btw, I encountered the issue at work on OSX and wrote this post with images generated at home on Linux. But thanks very much for testing it.

Comment: 10.3 issues are fixed in 10.4 (or earlier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response from support@wolfram.com:

> Thanks for contacting Wolfram Technical Support and for taking the time to send in the report. This is indeed a wrong behaviour of HighlightImage, specifically for how it deals with regions. I've filed an incidence report and I will keep you posted for any updates on this issue.
>
> Thanks again for bringing the issue to our attention, most appreciated.

## Update

It's a bit late, but for completeness, I want to mention that the issues above have been fixed and work properly in 11.3 (maybe in earlier 11 versions as well).